# Como registro variables en Tkinter?

Tags: python, visual-studio, tkinter

Soy principiante en Python como puedo hacer que se ingresen las variables en un entry y se guarden

```
def orden1():
num=int(input("Ingrese el numero de producto que desee ingresar: "))
product=[str(input("ingrese el producto: "))for x in range(num)] 
listinvt=[int(input("Ingrese los numeros de inventario: "))for x in range(num)]
```

Comment: Lo que buscas lograr es convertir el código que nos compartiste en una interfaz grafica de Tkinter con entrys?

Comment: Si ese es el caso, esta pagina puede ser de utilidad: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/caja-de-texto-entry-tkinter/